# How do I use BaseGameUtils when all of my activities already extend off of another?

Tags: java, android, api, console, achievements

*I have hit a problem with signing in to Google Play in my application for Google Play Services API.*  ***I am currently using BaseGameUtils for achievements, and I have found that to use it in an activity, the activity must extend BaseGameUtils, or BaseGameActivity.***

***Here* is where my problem is; All the the activities that I need to use BaseGameUtils with already extend classes that are required for proper function.** *Here's an example:*

```
    // This would be in Play.java, one of the main activities in use

    public class Play extends GameState {
        private boolean debug = true;

        // I want to extend BaseGameUtils from this class, yet I need to
        // Extend GameState to retain functional operation
    }
```

How would I go about doing this using BaseGameUtils if I can't extend from it, and how could I use it when, where I need it, already extends another class.

***P.S. I already have BaseGameUtils and everything needed set up and working. However without the sign in feature, it is useless and crashes the game. I have places a few try/catches in my code to stop this for debugging purposes.***

Answer (score 0):

Using `BaseGameActivity` is **not at all required**. Looking at the [source for BaseGameActivity](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/BaseGameActivity.java), it delegates all of the functionality to `GameHelper` which can be instantiated and used by any type of activity - just pass on the appropriate lifecycle events from your custom Activity classes to `GameHelper` directly.

Comment: If this is the case, then how would I use "Games.Achievements.unlock?" When I do not extend off of BaseGameUtils, it does not allow me to call things like getApiClient. 

I'm relatively new to the SDK, however I have a lot of experience with the JDK. I find that simple things like this prove to be difficult when it comes to the SDK.

Comment: You did look at the source code? BaseGameActivity's `getApiClient()` calls `GameHelper.getApiClient()`.